# Why is this image tracker not working? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a small click tracker for email links in my Laravel 5.2 app.

I use a string like this in my email view;

```
a href="http://example.com/tracker/1/{{ $slug }}"
```

Then in my controller, I look up the required URL by the tracker id (1 in the above case).  Then I create or update a tracking record with URL and user.  Finally, I redirect to the requested URL. No real magic, works just like I expected.

```
    public function track($id, $email){
    $track = Track::where('url', $id)->where('user', $email)->first();
    $url = TrackLink::where('id', $id)->first();

    if ($track){
        $track->count += 1;
        $track->save();
    } else {
        $track = new Track;
        $track->count = 1;
        $track->url = $id;
        $track->user = $email;
        $track->save();
    }

    if ($url->type == 'user'){
        return redirect ($url->url.'/'.$email); //in cases where I want to append the email to the url
    }else{
        if ($url->type == 'link') {
            return redirect ($url->url); //in cases where I just need to redirect
        }else{
            return redirect ($url->url); //this is the third case for images
        }
    }

}
```

However, I am trying to do the same with a 1x1 pixel png to track opens.  So, I am using a similar tracking string for the img src.  That part works in that it does call the method in the controller and write the track record.  However, the image won't display.

I have tried;

```
return ($url->url);
```

and

```
return redirect ($url->url);
```

Neither are getting the image file to present.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You should not alter your question with an answer. You must to post your own answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just didn't want to look like a dbag answering a question I asked!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The issue was with the if/else.  Removed the extra condition and the redirect was then reachable and executed properly.

Now looks like this;

```
    if ($url->type == 'user'){
        return redirect ($url->url.'/'.$email);
    }else{
        return redirect ($url->url);
    }
```